# Can I cancel my German Nation Visa?

Tags: visas, germany

I was planning on travelling to Germany for work (with a Type D German National Visa) and the visa has been stamped on my passport, but due to a family emergency, I would not be able to go to Germany and have changed my plans.

I have been reading up about it, and if my understanding is correct, the consulate will stamp "Cancelled without prejudice". Is it mandatory that I get my visa cancelled?

Comment: You could write them an email at _buergerservice@diplo.de_ and ask. Also see http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/AAmt/Krisenreaktionszentrum/Buergerservice/Buergerservice_node.html (in German). I would simply call and ask, but their hotline is closed for the day.